# How can I conserve hits to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure if for every call to `current_brain.current_vocab_badge`, there would be a separate call to the database.

If I have this :

```
  max_prog             = (current_brain.current_vocab_badge.topic.words.count * 2)
  comp_prog            = current_brain.current_vocab_badge.questions.where('style != ?', 'VisualPrereq').select{|q| q.weakness.blank? }.size
  { totes_left: remaining_prog, totes_so_far: comp_prog, cur_badge: current_brain.current_vocab_badge.name }
```

Would that be making 3 separate calls to the database for `current_brain.current_vocab_badge` where `current_brain` is instantiated in my application_controller as :

```
def current_brain
  current_user.brain
end
```

If so would it help to make an instance variable of it and then refer to that variable, or is my application_controller already achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would help

```
def current_brain
  @current_brain ||= current_user.brain
end
```